# how to set proxy server details on WebServiceTemplate

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

I have a SOAP webservice endpoint url(let's say :"EP1") which we can connect **only** through a proxy server.

We are using *org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate* class to consume webservices.

My question is, Is there a way that I can pass/set the proxy server details on WebServiceTemplate to connect to endpoint url "EP1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use VM arguments: `-Dhttp.proxyHost=mydomain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`

Having in mind that this setting applies to all HTTP requests made from Java.

Comment: it's not a solution and possibly leads to problems - especially when this JVM calls to other services

Answer (score 17):

You can specify custom `HttpClient` via `HttpComponentsMessageSender` when constructing the `WebServiceTemplate`. You can then pass default request config which includes the proxy to the client. Something like this should work:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig
        .custom()
        .setProxy(new HttpHost("host"))
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients
        .custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .build();

HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(client);

WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
wsTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender);
// Set other required properties ...
```

You might need to set other properties on the `WebServiceTemplate` object or the `HttpClient` depending on your needs so on. But this should demonstrate the basic concept.

Also take a look at [this sample](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) illustrating the usage of proxies in Apache HTTP client.

Comment: I had to do a minor tweak mentioned to get it working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748639/spring-ws-i-o-error-null-nested-exception-is-org-apache-http-client-clientpr - thanks a lot, this lead me to the solution!