# Set up proxy data to Spring SOAP web service template

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I'm working on an application where I have to consume a SOAP webservice and convert it to Rest based webservices. I followed [the tutorial from Spring team](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) and was capable to generate pojos, but when I try to make the call using the webServiceTemplate I have an error that the host is not recognized which is basically because I'm behind a proxy in our company.

The technology stack I'm using is Spring boot with web module and spring-ws-core, and I would like to know how to set up my proxy data in the webServiceTemplate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research, I came up with a programmatic solution. Once you defined your SOAP client that will extend  `WebServiceGatewaySupport` class, I created a configuration class (annotated with `@configuration` that will declare a bean of my SOAP client. In this method, I used the following code to setup my proxy information and thus I was able to consume my web service:

```
@Bean
    public CommerceSoapClient commerceSoapClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        CommerceSoapClient commerceService = new CommerceSoapClient();

        //Setup proxy
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor());
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080);
        builder.setProxy(proxy);


        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

        HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpClient);

        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender);
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("http://your webservice address path");
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);


        commerceService.setDefaultUri("https://your webservice address path");
        commerceService.setWebServiceTemplate(webServiceTemplate);

        return commerceService;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup the template according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881531/2746919).

Afterwards you should be able to set it within your class extending WebServiceGatewaySupport using

```
setWebServiceTemplate(WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I'm not using a virtual machine to set up this properties. Should I provide them as environment variables (I'm working on Windows OS)

Comment: Where exactly do you see a relation/restriction to a virtual machine?

Comment: I'm sorry, does the VM arguments mentioned in the response are arguments to use when launching the application ? Java -jar application.jar [properties]?!

Comment: Yes, that would be the JVM arguments: java -Dhttp.proxyHost=[yourProxy] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[yourPort] -jar application.jar

However be aware, that I linked to the answer below, which sets the proxy programmatically.

Comment: It didn't work with JVM arguments but I found a solution now. I posted my answer in case someone is facing the same problem.