# Spring - WebServiceTemplate with socks proxy

Tags: spring, soap, socks, webservicetemplate

I want to make SOAP request using proxy, but I need to use SOCKS instead of HTTP. Using `java.net.Proxy` I can build something like this:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("host", port));
```

Is there a way to pass this instance to `WebServiceTemplate`? I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879300/how-to-set-proxy-server-details-on-webservicetemplate#answer-33881531) for HTTP so can I do something like that?